# get all active participants in a channel meeting

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

Is there a way to list all the **active participants** in a [channel meeting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/tip-meet-in-a-channel-519ad2a0-9b74-49bb-97ee-0d4c4494a7c5) via the [MSFT Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api)?

This looks promising, [List participants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/call-list-participants?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), but how do I get the call `id`?

> Retrieve a list of participant objects in the call.

I also found [Get onlineMeeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) but:

> Note: The GET method is currently only supported for a VTC conference id. These IDs are generated for Cloud-Video-Interop licensed users and this method is used to get the details to join the meeting.

I'm guessing I'm not using VTC as I'm just using "regular Teams".

Comment: You can use [Create Call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-calls?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) using Graph API and try to fetch [Call Record](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/callrecords-callrecord-get?view=graph-rest-1.0) by passing call Id (which you will get it once your call get created) which returns all the participants joined that call

Answer (score 1):

No, without creating a call, you won't get the status of a channel meeting. Could you please raise an [UserVoice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/) if this needs to be consider as a future request.

Answer (score 0):

Posting the Answer for better knowledge

Copying from @Trinetra comments

You can use [Create Call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-calls?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) using Graph API and try to fetch [Call Record](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/callrecords-callrecord-get?view=graph-rest-1.0) by passing call Id (which you will get it once your call get created) which returns all the participants joined that call

Comment: so it sounds like the answer to my question is "no, can't be done currently", right?

Comment: yes, you will get the call records by passing the call id, please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/callrecords-callrecord-get?view=graph-rest-1.0#example-1-get-basic-details) for more info

Comment: but I don't want to create a call, I want to get the status of a channel meeting